# I can't open a Word doc because it's being used by someone else

Tags: mac, microsoft-word

I'm the only one using this computer. When I'm done with a document, I close it. Why would I be getting this pop up message? Then it asks if I want to open a copy of it but doesn't let me.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office decided long ago that it would use temporary files when they are working on documents. These files contain recent revisions or information about the documents currently open. While OSX hides these files by default (as does Windows, but it's easy to see them in Windows), they are still there.

When Office (any of the apps, really) open a document, they look for the temporary hidden file for the document. If they find one, they assume that either someone else is working on it, or that Office has crashed.

When you see it, you can sometimes get away with restarting the system, but that's annoying. What I have been doing is opening up a copy, save it somewhere else temporarily, then close Word completely. Remove the original file, then copy the "new" original file to the old location. I don't see that message anymore!

Typically, I see this message mostly when working over a network connection to an SMB (Samba) server.